# Can i pull html content from a exterior file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

This might be a really stupid question... But i'm making a menu. Would it be possible to write the code for that menu in an outside source? and then pull it using Jquery or javascript and have it replaced in a  location or something?

The menu would look like:

```
<span class="menulist">
  <span id="homemenu">
    <button id="home">Home</button<
  </span>
  <span id="onemenu">
    <button id="one">Page One</button<
  </span>
</span>
```

And have all that saved in a seperate file. I dn't care what type of file, .js, .txt, .html. and just pull the text and dump it as objects in a location specified for menu?

If this theoretically works here, I could use it elsewhere. such as writing the story narrative in one file and revealing it, or revealing it in part, and having the layout and technical workings on another file.

Comment: man ppl add down votes quick... :/ I honestly tried to find the answer first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Comment: ok... i'm getting the elements to load, but they are completely static. they are not selectable by jquery, seem to have no id, no class, nothing. using exact same info i cannot get it to work when i load the html content... am i doing it wrong?